# in-app billing basics for beginner

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, in-app-billing, ane

some might remember me from previous questions. I'm building an app for Android and it's going well. Most of the functions I wanted work great. I learned the basics by myself (and with the help of a few generous people here on StackOverflow!) but I still consider myself a beginner (today's question will show you how much of a beginner I am!).

My app is a dynamic map that shows the history of a country at a specific point in time. On Google Play, the user can download for free the base app (mostly empty), then he can buy packs (France, USA, UK, etc.) with in-app billing. That's where I am stuck.

I've bought the Milkman AndroidIAB ANE and read carefully the documentation ([this one](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-billing-ane.html)). I've managed to add the ANE to my library and update my application manifest. I've modified the example file to add my public key and the IDs for the purchasable packs. (I don't post the code here because I don't know if I'm allowed since the ANE is licensed.)

My app works that way:

1. First screen : Logo with a link to the website and a "Enter" button.
2. When clicked, the user arrive on a screen with a few buttons (one for each pack/country).
3. If the user click on a pack he owns, he is send to the chosen country's map.
4. If he doesn't own it, he is asked if he'd like to buy it and send to buy it.

Problems: (warning: some of those are worthy of noob of the month status, but I'm here to learn right?)

1. The code adapted from the Milkman's example is in an outside .as file used as DocumentClass.How do I link my screen 2 buttons with the functions from the .as file? 
   I tried this, but it doesn't work:

   ```
   franceBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAndPurchase);
   function checkAndPurchase (e:MouseEvent):void{
       purchasePack1(); 
   //function from the example, it checks if the pack is owned 
   // and send the user to the store if not
   };
   ```

EDIT 1: It is probably really easy to do, but I'm just not experienced enough to understand what I need to do I guess. 
I have a series of buttons in my app (say "franceBtn", "usaBtn" and "ukBtn"). Those buttons, when clicked, need to check if the pack ("francePack", "usaPack" and "ukPack") is owned by the user and if it is not, start the in-app purchase. I have tried to add an EventListener to the buttons, but nothing happens. Not on screen, not in the log.

2.Let's say the problem 1 is fixed. My app is meant to be used offline (except for buying additional packs). The way I understood what I read is that the "inventory" of in-app purchased packs is obtained via Google Play, which means (if I'm not mistaken) that the user needs to be online. Is there a way to create a file of some kind inside the device that stores this "inventory" so it can be accessed offline?

EDIT 2: I want the user to be able to use the app from everywhere, without the need to be online (except for purchasing packs obviously). But I guess that the app checks with Google Play in order to know which pack is already owned. So I'm looking for a way to store the "inventory" of owned packs directly inside the device/app (so it can be accessed offline and updated everytime internet starts. 
I hope it is more clear, and thank you for pointing out it was not.

I've read the doc quite a few times, and I'm really stuck, so please, I'd really appreciate any help. ;)

Thanks in advance,
Jeryl

EDIT 3: Here is the portion of my code relating to IAB (made by following this tutorial :[here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-billing-ane.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20developer_center_tutorials%20%28Adobe%20Developer%20Center%20RSS%20Feed%29) but I didn't really understand it. I'm willing to learn but this is an intermediate level tuto, and I've found nothing on Internet that explains what to do for real beginners. If you have links I couldn't find, I'm all hears :D )

```
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.*;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.events.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


if (AndroidIAB.isSupported()) {
    AndroidIAB.create();
}


// listeners for billing service startup
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.SERVICE_READY, onReady);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.SERVICE_NOT_SUPPORTED, onUnsupported);

// start the service
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.startBillingService("my_key");

function onReady(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    trace("service now ready- you can now make purchases.");

}

function onUnsupported(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    trace("sorry, in app billing won't work on this phone!");

}

// listen for inventory events

AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.INVENTORY_LOADED, onInventoryLoaded);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingErrorEvent.LOAD_INVENTORY_FAILED, onInventoryFailed);

function onInventoryLoaded(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    for each(var purchase: AndroidPurchase in e.purchases) {
        trace("You own the item:" + purchase.itemId);
    }
}

function onInventoryFailed(e: AndroidBillingErrorEvent): void {
    trace("Something went wrong loading inventory: " + e.text);
}

// load the player's current inventory
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();

// listen for purchase events
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.PURCHASE_SUCCEEDED, onPurchaseSuccess);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingErrorEvent.PURCHASE_FAILED, onPurchaseFailed);

function onPurchaseSuccess(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    var purchase: AndroidPurchase = e.purchases[0];
    trace("you purchased the item " + purchase.itemId);
    AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();
}

function onPurchaseFailed(e: AndroidBillingErrorEvent): void {
    trace("Something went wrong with the purchase of " + e.itemId + ": " + e.text);
}

franceBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPackOneButtonClicked);

function onPackOneButtonClicked(e: MouseEvent) {
    if (purchase.itemId == "packone") {
        franceMap.visible = true;
    } else {
        AndroidIAB.androidIAB.purchaseItem("packone");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your patience! Jeryl

Comment: Sorry Jeryl, I have worked with Milkman ANE for IAP but I am not able to understand what are you trying to say in your first question. Can you please elaborate your questions so that we may be in a better position to help you.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear, English is not my first language. I will edit the post to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding, I am assuming that you have properly set up the products in IAP section of Google play.

Now for your first question, I am not sure about the problem as clicking on a button and something to be done on that event should have worked out of the box. Your code should be something along the lines:

( Assuming you have two packs and their itemIds are  **com.yourcomapny.packOne**  and **com.yourcompany.packTwo**)

```
franceBtn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onPackOneButtonClicked );

function onPackOneButtonClicked( event:MouseEvent )
{
  if( !isPackOnePurchased() )
  {
    purchasePackOne();
  }
}

// Similarly for pack two
```

This is pretty much the same code , you are trying to write. Perhaps we can help you more with your problem, if you can post some portion of the code which is not working.

For your second part, if you want to store the "inventory" information offline, you may proceed in the following way:

1) Lets say you create an empty file.

2) Lets say if a person buys **com.yourcompany.packTwo** and you received purchase Successful event, you just add **com.yourcompany.packTwo** to the file and thus marking it as purchased.

3) Whenever you call isPackOnePurchased or isPackTwoPurchased, it checks whether corresponding itemId is present in the file and decide whether this package needs to be bought or it is already bought.

This will get you started. Another thing for enhanced user experience and security is that whenever user clicks on a button to buy the pack ( and he/she is connected to the internet ), always check whether that pack is in the inventory or not and show the feedback according to that. Always sync your local state with inventory, if there is any inconsistency. The inconsistency may arise if user deletes their application data and then tries to open the pack. This check will ensure that your application is synced with server state.

If you want next level of security you can either encrypt the information( item Ids in this case ) and store it a secure database.

Encryption can be done using numerous encryption methods. One such method is [Rijndael encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). You can use this tool [this online tool](http://rijndael.online-domain-tools.com) for generating encrypted strings for your itemIds. This will give you a feel of what I am trying to say.

For how to store information in local database in an AIR based applications, see [this link from Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have set up the products in Google Play, so the problem doesn't come from there. I will try this tonight after class and come back to inform you of the result.

Comment: Hey again. I have no idea what doesn't work. I have made my app without real troubles, but this is just above my level (but desperately needed to finish :/ ). I've updated the original question with the portion of the code. If you've not lost all patience, could you take a look and help me out again? Really appreciated! Jeryl

Comment: @Jeryl Please tell me, are you getting any traces on AndroidBillingEvent.SERVICE_READY or not. Also are you even getting inside onPackOneButtonClicked listener function.It will be possible to solve your problem if we may break down into small sub problems. So lets start with your MouseEvent listener first

Comment: I don't get traces because when I test the app on my computer, i have an error (because not supported). So i add a textfield that reads "Ready" if the service is ready. It works when I try the app on my phone. I tried to do the same for onPackOneButtonClicked, but the second textfield remains empty when I click on the button. And nothing else happens.

Comment: Which button component are you using?

Comment: franceBtn is not really a button, it's a movieclip. Does it have to be a button? Because in the rest of the app, my "buttons" are movieclips and it works.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a button. With your limited info, I am not able to reproduce your problem. If you have added an event listener to a movie clip and listened to it correctly, it should have worked. This has nothing to do with InAppBilling

Comment: then I'm really confused. The rest of the code has no problem (that I'm aware of). May be if you see my whole fla it would help? If you don't mind, my email in on my profile, contact me and I will send it to you. In any case, thanks for the help!